# Problema métodos print() printf() en Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

He instalado Apache Netbeans y cuando ejecuto el programa en el que me debe pedir una entrada de teclado indicado por el método printf() resulta que debo insertar primero la entrada de teclado y después me pide la entrada de teclado del método printf. Para ello adjunto un codigo y su resultado:

```
public class RegexTextHarness_01 {
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.printf("%nEnter your regex: ");
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(in.nextLine());

        System.out.printf("%nEnter input string to search: ");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(in.nextLine());

        boolean found = false;
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.printf("I found the text" +
                    " \"%s\" starting at " +
                    "index %d and ending at index %d.%n",
                    matcher.group(),matcher.start(),matcher.end());
            found = true;
        }
        if(!found){
            System.out.printf("No match found.%n");
        }
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Resultado:

```
--- exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:exec (default-cli) @ mavenproject4 ---

DOG
DOGF
Enter your regex: Enter input string to search: I found the text "DOG" starting at index 0 and ending at index 3.
```

Comment: ¿Para qué pones `%n` al principio de las primeras cadenas?

Comment: Gracias por responder. Primero, decir que dicho código lo he copiado, y segundo, que aunque quite %n obtengo el mismo resultado. El problema no lo tengo ahí.

Comment: Si no sabes que hace en un principio, ¿cómo sabes lo que causa al final?

Comment: Con el método print() también me ocurre lo mismo. Son ejercicios que yo ya tenía hechos y al cambiar al nuevo Apache-Netbeans me ocurre esto. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Ya he conseguido resolverlo. He desinstalado Apache-Netbeans 12.4 y e instalado Apache-Netbeans 11.3. Ahora me funciona correctamente. Saludos cordiales.